# The Comprehend class in the boto3 client does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am attempting to use boto3 client (v.1.4.8) to access the AWS comprehend service to evaluate small user-defined strings. But when I attempt to use the client, it doesn't work.

The [documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/docs/reference/services/comprehend.html#client).

The code I used:

```
client = boto3.client('comprehend')
```

The exception I'm being thrown:

> ```
> UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'comprehend'.
> ```
>
> Valid service names are: acm,...

I'm guessing there has to be something going on that I'm not aware of

Comment: Check your boto3 version.

Answer (score 2):

I am using boto3(v.1.5.22) and it works well in it. So, if you don't have problem working on higher version you can try it. Amazon comprehend was released recently so that have support for higher version of boto3 only